# Scrollbar en Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-2.x, scrollbar

tengo un problema con un scrollbar en Tkinter.
Al agregar el scrollbar, no me muestra la pantalla completa y debo maximizarla yo, me gustaria que la pantalla aparezca con el tamaño que yo le di (800x600).
Les dejo un fragmento del codigo.

Originalmente resizable iria en (0,0)

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import os

ventana3=Tk()

ventana3.title("Panecillos")

ventana3.resizable(1,1)

ventana3.iconbitmap("Fox.ico")

ventana3.config(bg="SteelBlue4", width="800", heigh="600", relief="sunken", bd=20)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(ventana3)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )

juegoP=Label(ventana3, bg="SteelBlue4", text="Bienvenido" + nombre + "Estoy pensando en un numero de %s digitos. Intenta adivinar cual es." % (digitosNum)).place(x=175, y=30)
juegoP2=Label(ventana3, bg="SteelBlue4",text="\nAqui hay algunas pistas:").place(x=175, y=50)
juegoP3=Label(ventana3, bg="SteelBlue4", text="Cuando digo:    Eso significa:").place(x=175, y=70)
JuegoP4=Label(ventana3, bg="SteelBlue4", text ="\nPico:     Una de las cifras esta en el numero secreto, pero no en el lugar correcto.").place(x=175, y=90)
JuegoP5=Label(ventana3, bg="SteelBlue4", text="Fermi:   Tu intento tiene una cifra correcta en el lugar correcto.").place(x=175, y=125)
JuegoP6=Label(ventana3, bg="SteelBlue4", text="Panecillos:  Ningun digito es correcto.").place(x=175, y=145)
```

Comment: Con .config le defines la configuración por defecto. Si quitas la barra de desplazamiento verás que es la que adopta. Al ponerla, la ventana3 adopta el tamaño de esta, ya que no has forzado que su geometría sea 800x600 añadiendo la línea que ha propuesto Mir cea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para cambiar el tamaño de una ventana hay que usar `ventana3.geometry("800x600")` no con el .config

Comment: Gracias, es lo que necesitaba :)